# Font size transition not smooth on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-animations

I am trying to apply transition on font-size property. Its working smooth on desktop browser but in case of mobile browsers e.g. android chrome or iOS chrome or safari the transition of font-size is not smooth.

Below is the CSS

```
.dummy-text{
        font-size: 24px;
        transition: font-size 0.5s linear;
    }
```

Below is the fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/3y7zbv0c/1/

Can some one tell me how to make it smooth on mobile devices browsers?

Comment: You can use @animation instead of transition. It is better performance.

Comment: That doesn’t look exactly smooth on desktop either. Try if you can use a scale transform instead, that usually gives (a little) better results.

Comment: It is smooth in jsbin

Comment: It has no relation with jsbin or jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

If you use animations with @keyframes the performance will be better than `transition`. Your problem however is the javascript to increase the size of the text. Here you are the solution without javascript:

https://jsfiddle.net/3y7zbv0c/2/

```css
@keyframes example {
  from {font-size: 24px;}
  to {font-size: 34px;}
}
.dummy-text{
  font-size: 24px;
  animation: example 4s infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="dummy-text">
  This is text
</div>
```

Comment: It is better but still its little choppy.

Comment: So change the mobile device. Two things: or your webpage is too big to proccess all effects with a mobile device, or the mobile device is too old and it's not sufficient RAM.

Comment: I have htc one m8. Device is not an issue, even the code I am running is very simple one no too much html.

Comment: I have tried to change the font type from px to em just to verify but still no luck.

Comment: I see it very smooth in PC and with an iPhone 6. Device sometimes is the problem. Android have less performance than iOS, it needs more RAM to run smoothy.